# Parsing XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I know taht there already are many question about this subject but I haven't find the solution for my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <PeopleCountingServiceHeader xmlns="http://localhost/countingws/">
            <Username>username</Username>
            <Password>password</Password>
            <Camera>essai</Camera>
        </PeopleCountingServiceHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <InsertData xmlns="http://ai-sense.com/counting/">
            <impacts>
                <Impact>
                    <TimeStamp>2014-10-23T15:17:51.879</TimeStamp>
                    <Type>Output</Type>
                    <Layer>0</Layer>
                </Impact>
                <Impact>
                    <TimeStamp>2014-10-23T15:17:52.753</TimeStamp>
                    <Type>Input</Type>
                    <Layer>0</Layer>
                </Impact>
                <Impact>
                    <TimeStamp>2014-10-23T15:17:54.375</TimeStamp>
                    <Type>Output</Type>
                    <Layer>0</Layer>
                </Impact>
                <Impact>
                    <TimeStamp>2014-10-23T15:17:55.186</TimeStamp>
                    <Type>Input</Type>
                    <Layer>0</Layer>
                </Impact>
                <Impact>
                    <TimeStamp>2014-10-23T15:18:28.897</TimeStamp>
                    <Type>Output</Type>
                    <Layer>0</Layer>
                </Impact>
                <Impact>
                    <TimeStamp>2014-10-23T15:18:29.771</TimeStamp>
                    <Type>Input</Type>
                    <Layer>0</Layer>
                </Impact>
                <Impact>
                    <TimeStamp>2014-10-23T15:22:41.219</TimeStamp>
                    <Type>Output</Type>
                    <Layer>0</Layer>
                </Impact>
            </impacts>
        </InsertData>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I want to retrieve for example the username.

I have already try somethinf like this :

```
$request =simplexml_load_file("php://input", NULL, TRUE);
echo "request: "$request->{"soap:Header"}->PeopleCountingServiceHeader->Username;
```

How can I access to my datas ?

Comment: This is not just XML, but SOAP. Have you read about [ext/soap](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)?

Comment: @ThW No didn't know that there is a direference ^^ I will take a look.

Comment: @ThW Humm I'm not actually shure of what is SOAP...

Comment: SOAP is an XML format to transfer objects between systems. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP . You could parse it manually, but a specific SOAP implementation is a lot more convenient.

Comment: @ThW Thank you a lot, I'm trying to learn how to use it; it's a bit more complicated than I was figuring me :-P If you can post this as answer, I will be able to mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not just XML, but SOAP. PHP has a specific extension for it: [ext/soap](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php).

[SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) is an XML format to transfer objects between systems. You could parse it manually, but a specific SOAP implementation is a lot more convenient.

If you parse in manually you have to consider the namespaces. Here are 3 namespaces in your example XML:

1. `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` - the SOAP envelope, using a `soap` prefix/alias
2. `http://localhost/countingws/` - elements inside soap:Header, no prefix/alias
3. `http://ai-sense.com/counting/` - elements inside soap:Body, no prefix/alias

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! I will search about how to use namespaces with SimpleXMLElement php class